# How to Make Transparent SVG Transparent in Java?

Tags: java, svg, jscrollpane, batik

I have SVG file that actually empty, that have no element, yet. I will manipulate it in the java code by adding element. The SVG file will be inserted in a scrollpane. The problem is even the SVG file actually empty, the Scrollpane not transparent even if I have already set it transparent.

Here is the SVG file (I got it from client):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 13.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 14948)  -->
<svg version="1.1"
 baseProfile="full"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
 id="chart"
 width="1366px" height="768px" viewBox="0 0 1366 768" >
<defs>
   <!-- some template here -->
</defs>
</svg>
```

and here is the scroll pane part (canvasDiagram is the SVGCanvas).

```
// the instantiation part
canvasDiagram.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC);
canvasDiagram.setURI(getClass().getResource("path to svg file").toString());
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(canvasDiagram){
        {
            setOpaque(false);
            getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        }
    };
```

The scrollpane is not transparent but white. I tried to insert the scroll pane content with transparent jPanel and its work so I believe the white content because of the canvasDiagram. Can you help me to make the empty part of canvasDiagram really transparent?

Comment: `transparnet.png`? Why are you using a png file there? SVG or PNG?

Comment: That is to make the scroll pane transparent. It is kind of work around. What I wanted to make transparent is the canvasDiagram. I've edited so it might be clearer

Comment: "Is it the fault in the XML definition?" For me, this sounds like a fault in Java. BTW: [Don't include a DOCTYPE declaration](https://jwatt.org/svg/authoring/#doctype-declaration)

Comment: So its the Java, eh? I will remove the XML tag.
Okay. I will delete all DTD in my SVG. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found that setting a background with alpha value works more reliable than setting `isOpaque(false)`

```
setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

Comment: is is possible to show just the borders? cause I used this, and the borders dissappeared as well